# Fade effect attribute/function in javascript custom script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add a fade effect on my javascript function

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
  loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');
  fader = document.getElementById('login_fader');
  login_box = document.getElementById('login_box');
  closebtn = document.getElementById('closelogin');
  loginBtn.onclick=function(){
    fader.style.display = "block";
    login_box.style.display = "block";
  }
  closebtn.onclick=function() {
    fader.style.display = "none";
    login_box.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="login_fader">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="login_box">
  <table class="table-login">
    <th>Login or Register</th>
    <th><a id="closelogin">X</a></th>
    <tr>
      <td>Login</td>
  <td>Register</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  #loginBtn {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -6%;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  #login_fader {
   background: black;
   opacity: .5;
   -moz-opacity: .5;
   -filter: alpha(opacity=50);
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 5;
   display: none;
  }
#login_box {
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px white solid:
  background: #5a5a5a;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 35%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

.table-login {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

#closelogin {
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/U3n4j/

I have tried using the `transition` properties from css3 and tried applying both to `login_box` and `login_fader`.
I found some functions on the net but don't know how to link them to my already made function and i was thinking if there are any properties directly that i can link them to my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proper way to fade in a static box in css3 and js 1.7 ++**

This is a example using only webkit and modern javascripts `classList.add`

but you can add the other prefixes.`-moz,-ms,-o`

*in this example i show only the animation.*

css

```
.box{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;top:-100%;/*notice TOP -100%*/
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 700ms ease,top 0 linear 700ms;/*notice TOP delay*/
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.box.active{
 -webkit-transition:opacity 700ms ease,top 0 linear 0;
 /*top transition not needed but could help to understand*/
 top:0;
 opacity:1;
}
```

js

```
function show(){
 box.classList.add('active');
}
function hide(){
 box.classList.remove('active');
}
var box=document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0],
button=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
button.addEventListener('click',show,false);
box.addEventListener('click',hide,false);
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/RAu8Q/ not working anymore

http://jsfiddle.net/RAu8Q/17/ **new syntax 10-2015**

if you have any questions just ask.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what effect you're trying to achieve, but if you're going to use CSS transitions, then you need to be transitioning between numerical properties. I.e., you can't expect a fade to occur simply by transitioning from `display:block` to `display:none`. You'd want to use opacity instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't try to use `css` transitions in conjunction with display property, **that won't work**! Instead, try transitioning other properties. Let's take `opacity` for instance (we'll simulate `display`: `none`/`block` functionality by setting `opacity` to 0/1)

Secondly, set the start value for opacity to `0` on the desired `HTML` element (the one you'd like to animate). Specify which property to animate (`opacity` in our case):

```
transition: opacity 1s;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s;
-webkit-transtion: opacity 1s;
```

When the login button is clicked, set opacity to 1:

```
loginBtn.onclick=function() {
    fader.style.opacity = 1;
    login_box.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

When the close button is clicked, set opacity back to 0:

```
closebtn.onclick=function() {
    fader.style.opacity = 0;
    login_box.style.opacity = 0;
  }
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/U3n4j/6/) to fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do needs css animations. So just create an animation class that fades out the target element and apply it after the user logs in.

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from: {
        opacity:1;
    },
    to: {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

then use apply it on the class

```
.fadeOut {
     animation:fadeOut 0.25s forwards;
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/zgPrc/